# Affidavit v. deposition

Tags: difference

What's the difference between "affidavit" and "deposition"? They can both mean "a formal written statement that can be used in court", can't they? Or does making an affidavit involve taking an oath beforehand while making a deposition doesn't?

Comment: You might get a better answer to this question on the Law Stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, from my experience with U.S. television legal dramas... (I am not a lawyer)

- An affidavit is written.
- A deposition is spoken.

Furthermore, it seems to me that an affidavit is any written statement that is certified by signature while the signatory is under oath.  In many ways this is just a one-way "broadcast" kind of statement by the witness to the court (and whoever brought-in the witness will try to steer the witness toward helpful statements and away from unhelpful statements in a pre-signature editing process).

However, a deposition tends to be more of a question-and-answer session that occurs while the witness is under oath (and is later transcribed).  In this situation, the format actually lets opposing counsel ask questions of the witness and so the format is more of a back-and-forth rather than being *purely* broadcast.

Comment: How is deposition different from interrogation?

Answer (score 1):

A deposition is (in the US) oral testimony, not written.

> Deposition testimony is taken orally, with an attorney asking questions and the deponent (the individual being questioned) answering while a court reporter or tape recorder (or sometimes both) records the testimony. Deposition testimony is generally taken under oath, and the court reporter and the deponent often sign affidavits attesting to the accuracy of the subsequent printed transcript.

[source](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/deposition)